# Identify User Browser in Javascript and pass to asp.net c# to display error page if not IE browser

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, browser

Trying to identify browser type using Javascript and then pass the variable to asp.net (c#). However this is not working. The system is very old and written in VS 2008.

When using just the code behind code, it works on some pc's, but others pass through the wrong browser type (ie: when using 'IE' they say they are using 'Mozilla')

So I tried adding the code in the JS and nothing changed. I have tried numerous solutions on the web, but have not been successful.

My code is as follows:

Code behind

```css
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

string BrowserType=Request.Browser.Browser;
if (!(BrowserType=="Internet Explorer" || BrowserType=="IE")) {
  Response.Redirect("Error.aspx?BrType=" + BrowserType);
}
```

JS

```js
var browser = (function(agent) {
  switch (true) {
    case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1:
      return "edge";
    case agent.indexOf("edg") > -1:
      return "edge dev/can";
    case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr:
      return "opera";
    case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome:
      return "chrome";
    case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1:
      return "ie";
    case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1:
      return "firefox";
    case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1:
      return "safari";
    default:
      return "other";
  }
})(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

console.log(browser)
```

Please help.

Comment: are you not getting a useragent header in every request header as per docs from 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: If you need the information of the browser being IE or not, you can simply check `typeof ScriptEngine === 'function'`.

Comment: Saravanan, I have reviewed the docs you mentioned and am trying to implement this, however it is telling me I am missing an assembly reference, but I cannot figure out what I am missing.  I have modified my code above to include the assemblies.

Comment: I am getting a useragent header, but it seems to be parsing the incorrect one.  If I run as IE it says I am using Mozilla,  If I run as Firefox it says FireFox, If I run as Chrome it says AppleMAC-Safari, If I run using Internal Web Browser it runs fine.